# Use helper service from a Twig Extension in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, twig

I'm trying to set a twig filter working this way: {{entities|fieldnames}} that will return an array containing the properties names of a entity object.
My problem, after reading and trying for hours, is that I'm not able to execute $this->container->get("helpers")  from the Twig Extension php. It seems that I'm not linking the service container properly... Help, please ;)

**Error:** Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /Users/a77/Dropbox/06.Proyectos/2011 U-Vox/DEV U-Vox/Uvox Web/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Extension/FieldnamesTwigExtension.php line 38

Or if construct without =null
**Error**
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\FieldnamesTwigExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\Container, none given, called in

**services.yml**

> services:
>
> ```
> helpers:
>     class:        Acme\DemoBundle\Services\Helpers
>
> twig.extension.acme.demo:
>     class:        Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\Extension\DemoExtension
>     arguments:    [twig.loader]
>
> acme.demo.listener:
>     class:        Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener
>     arguments:    [twig.extension.acme.demo]
>
> fieldnames:
>     class: Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\FieldnamesTwigExtension
>     arguments:  [@service_container]
> ```

**Extension\FieldnamesTwigExtension.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Extension;

class FieldnamesTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
private $container;
public function __construct(Container $container=null)
{
    $this->container = $container;
    //var_dump ($container); exit; //  prints null !!!

}
 protected function get($service)
{
    return $this->container->get($service);
}

public function getFilters() {
    return array(
        'fieldnames' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'fieldnamesFilter'),
    );
}

public function getName() {
    return 'fieldnames_twig_extension';
}

public function fieldnamesFilter($obj) {
    if (is_array($obj)) {
        $first = $obj[0];

// GET (HELPERS) NOT WORKING :

       $fieldnames = $this->container->get("helpers")->getFieldnames($first);
        return $fieldnames;
    }
    return null;
}

public function twig_array_get_function($array, $name) {
    return $array[$name];
}

}
```

**Helpers.php**

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Services;

class Helpers {

public function sum($n1, $n2) {
    return $n1 + $n2;
}

public function getFieldnames($entities) {
    $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($entities[0]);
    $props = $reflect->getProperties();
    $fieldnames = Array();
    foreach ($props as $prop) {
        $fieldnames[] = $prop->getName();
    }
    return $fieldnames;
 }

}
```

**AcmeDemoExtension.php**

> namespace Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection;
>
> use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder; use
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader; use
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension; use
>   Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator; use
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition; // Added
>
> class AcmeDemoExtension extends Extension {
>
> ```
> public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) {
>
>     $definition = new Definition('Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\AccessTwigExtension');
>     $definition->addTag('twig.extension');
>     $container->setDefinition('access_twig_extension', $definition);
>
>     $definition2 = new Definition('Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\FieldnamesTwigExtension');
>     $definition2->addTag('twig.extension');
>     $container->setDefinition('fieldnames_twig_extension', $definition2);
>
>
>     $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
>     $loader->load('services.yml');
> }
>
> public function getAlias() {
>     return 'acme_demo';
> }
>
>  }
> ```

Comment: If you want to make this works, you should put "namespace" before "use", remove the "definition" lines and finally update the getFieldnames to       public function getFieldnames($record) {
        $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($record);
        $props = $reflect->getProperties();
        $fieldnames = Array();
        foreach ($props as $prop) {
            $fieldnames[] = $prop->getName();
        }
        return $fieldnames;
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your code on my application and had the same error. To resolve it :

**Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection\AcmeDemoExtension.php**

Remove this lines :

```
$definition2 = new Definition('Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\FieldnamesTwigExtension');
$definition2->addTag('twig.extension');
$container->setDefinition('fieldnames_twig_extension', $definition2);
```

**Acme\DemoBundle\Resources\config\services.yml**

Replace this lines:

```
fieldnames:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\FieldnamesTwigExtension
    arguments:  [@service_container]
```

By :

```
fieldnames:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\FieldnamesTwigExtension
    arguments:  [@service_container]
    tags: [{ name: twig.extension }]
```

Comment: You beat me to it though I think just injecting the helpers instead of the full container is a slightly better approach.

Comment: Did both editings, but still no luck, but I got a new error: 

ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\FieldnamesTwigExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\Container, instance of appDevDebugProjectContainer given, called in /Users/a77/Dropbox/06.Proyectos/2011 U-Vox/DEV U-Vox/Uvox Web/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 718 and defined in /Users/a77/Dropbox/06.Proyectos/2011 U-Vox/DEV U-Vox/Uvox Web/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Extension/FieldnamesTwigExtension.php line 23

Comment: Just changed the order of namespace & use and now I'm seeing the object returned. I'm coming back in a few minutes... Thanks to both!

Comment: Now working except, don't know why the line  $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($entities[0]); was working if I was using the helpers service from a controller, not from the current Extension call where it warns me against treating $entities  as an array. Any idea about this ? Thanks again to both.

Comment: FatalErrorException</abbr>: Error: Cannot use object of type Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Banned as array in /Users/a77/Dropbox/06.Proyectos/2011 U-Vox/DEV U-Vox/Uvox Web/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Services/Helpers.php line 14

Comment: yes, first namespace, second use, and now the problem is only in how the entities from {{entities|fieldnames}} is sent to the helper service...

Comment: That is because in your twig extension you are checking for an array and popping the entity off if it.  The helper assumes it is getting an array when in fact it is getting an entity.  Looks like you got past the container issue.

Comment: A var_dump($entites) will probably help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are making this too hard.  You should be injecting helpers directly into you twig extension.  You should also be doing your tagging in services.yml.  Not in the dependency injection extension.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

services.yml

```
fieldnames:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\FieldnamesTwigExtension
    arguments:  [@helpers]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

And adjust the rest of your code accordingly.

Comment: I was planning to enhance my code using yes only the required service, not the full container... but none of the approaches are working

Answer (score 1):

In your **Extension\FieldnamesTwigExtension.php**, is this normal that your `namespace` is called after `use` instruction ?

Which error Symfony return ?

Comment: Error added now on the original post. Thanks. Unfortunately changing the order of namespace and use did not solve the problem ...

Comment: Well, it made a big part of the solution